# Einstein Email Recommendations the same for everybody

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

During our Einstein implementation we noticed that the recommendations are the same for everyone we preview the mail on. However, when I look at the Reporting tab in Email Recommendations and view some random contacts I see that there are views and purchases being tracked.

So there are product views, purchases and add-to-carts being tracked, why doesn't Einstein take this data into account when determining which products to show? Instead it shows the same 2 products for everybody. Are we overseeing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which recommendation Scenario do you use?

Comment: The standard Best Practice scenario, I played around with the order a bit but it didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: in reporting > contacts what is the value for email? and is that the same value you are passing in the call for the part %%emailaddress%%

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We are experiencing the exact same issue, with data correctly flowing in and any adjustments not affecting the results shown.